# Javascript Regex: How to specify option end of string

Tags: javascript, regex

So say I have an element I'm trying to grab that looks like (The important part is the end)

```
<inline id="shortcode0-container" class="shortcode-container linkContainer" data-content="ANNOTATION "><inline class="shortcode-header hidden"><ul class="shortcode-menu nav"><li class="shortcode-label"><a href="#">Annotation: Jordan</a></li><li class="divider-vertical"></li><li class="shortcode-unlink"><a href="#">unlink</a></li></ul></inline><inline class="shortcode" id="shortcode0"><div class="shortcode-preview">
<a href="#">Jordan</a>
</div></inline></inline>&nbps; blah blah blah text here
```

Sometimes the &nbsp? isn't there. i don't want to have 2 patterns to capture the end of this element. Heres what i've got so far

```
/(<inline.*?\n.*?\n.*?(<\/inline><\/inline>&nbsp;|<\/inline><\/inline>))/gm
```

Right now i'm having to use either

```
/(<inline.*?\n.*?\n.*?<\/inline><\/inline>)/gm
```

or

```
/(<inline.*?\n.*?\n.*?&nbsp;)/gm
```

Any clues on how to combine them?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:**

Thanks to Bergi, had to modify his response a bit. Added a `?` to the `&nbsp;` group as it was causing nothing to be seen if the `&nbsp;` wasn't there

```
/(<inline.*?\n.*?\n.*?<\/inline><\/inline>(?:&nbsp;?)?)/gm
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you want a simple [optional token](http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) (maybe as a [non-capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)):

```
/(<inline.*?\n.*?\n.*?<\/inline><\/inline>(?:&nbsp;)?)/gm
#                                         ^^^      ^^
```

Comment: Awesome that worked :). Just to clarify the ?: part makes it non capturing?

Comment: Hey had to make a modification.

    /(<inline.*?\n.*?\n.*?<\/inline><\/inline>(?:&nbsp;?)?)/gm

Added an optional token after the &nbsp; group

Comment: Uh, there is already an "optional" modifier for that group (right after it)? The one you did add makes the semicolon in the group optional.

Comment: I had to add it in between the last 2 closing parenthesis to get it to work for some reason.

Comment: Looks like when you removed the capturing group around the `</inline></inline>…`, you deleted the wrong closing parenthesis. Check my edit.